# How to update hook values after concatenation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a socket connection to a server, the moment user posts a HTTP request to that server and that socket connection responds with a pending status, I concatenate a new notification with loading state to the Notification Box citing the given action has been fired and that it's now loading, after the action has been loaded & is ready socket server fires an event signaling the action is ready, therefore I must change the previous notification state from loading to ready, How can I change the concatenated notification state to ready?

```
useEffect(() => {

    const onSuccess = () => {
        alert('success')
    };

    const onFailure = () => {
        alert('failed')
    };
    const handleSocketEvent = (event: SocketEvent) => {
        switch (event.state) {
            case ActionStatus.SUCCESS:
                if (event.service.power_state === ServerStatus.POWERED_OFF) {
                     #Here I should change the concatenated hook to ready
                } else if (event.service.power_state === ServerStatus.POWERED_ON) {
                     #Here I should change the concatenated hook to ready
                }
                break;

            case ActionStatus.FAILED:
                if (event.service.power_state === ServerStatus.POWERED_OFF) {
                    onSuccess();
                }  else if (event.service.power_state === ServerStatus.POWERED_ON) {
                     #Here I should change the concatenated hook to failed
                }
                break;

            case ActionStatus.PENDING:
                newNotifications({
                    name : event.service.name,
                    action : event.task.name,
                    created_at : event.task.created_at,
                    uuid : event.task.uuid,
                    state: 'pending'
                })
                break;
        }
    };

    const channel = echo.private(`Notification.${user.user_id}`);
    channel
        .listen(".ServerDetails.virtualMachine.powerOn",  handleSocketEvent)
        .listen(".ServerActions.virtualMachine.powerOn",  handleSocketEvent)
        .listen(".ServerDetails.virtualMachine.powerOff", handleSocketEvent)
        .listen(".ServerActions.virtualMachine.powerOff", handleSocketEvent);

    return () => echo.leaveChannel(`Notification.${user.user_id}`);
}, [echo, user]);
```

Below are my notifications context where I send my get request and load them all.

```
const {notifications, newNotifications, loadingNotifs} = useContext(NotificationContext);
```

And here's the implementation of my newNotifications function.

```
const newNotifications = (notification: any) => {
    setNotification((notifications : any) => {
        return notifications.reverse().concat(notification);
    });
}
```

Note that, the reason I'm raising this question is that, I don't want to generate a new notification denoting the action is ready or else, I just need to update the already concatenated notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `NotificationContext` needs to also expose out the `setNotification` function, or a function to "updateNotification" that takes the `uuid` and new "state" as arguments.

   ```
   const updateNotification = (uuid: string, state: string) => {
     setNotification((notifications: any[]) => {
       return notifications.map(
         notification => notification.uuid === uuid
           ? {
             ...notification,
             state
           }
           : notification
       )
     });
   };
   ```
2. Call this utility and pass in the required arguments.

   ```
   const {
     notifications,
     newNotifications,
     loadingNotifs,
     updateNotification
   } = useContext(NotificationContext);

   ...

   const handleSocketEvent = (event: SocketEvent) => {
     switch (event.state) {
       case ActionStatus.SUCCESS:
         if (event.service.power_state === ServerStatus.POWERED_OFF) {
           // Here I should change the concatenated hook to ready
           updateNotification(event.task.uuid, 'ready');
         } else if (event.service.power_state === ServerStatus.POWERED_ON) {
           // Here I should change the concatenated hook to ready
           updateNotification(event.task.uuid, 'ready');
         }
         break;

       case ActionStatus.FAILED:
         if (event.service.power_state === ServerStatus.POWERED_OFF) {
           onSuccess();
         }  else if (event.service.power_state === ServerStatus.POWERED_ON) {
           // Here I should change the concatenated hook to failed
           updateNotification(event.task.uuid, 'failed');
         }
         break;

       case ActionStatus.PENDING:
       default:
         newNotifications({
           name : event.service.name,
           action : event.task.name,
           created_at : event.task.created_at,
           uuid : event.task.uuid,
           state: 'pending'
         })
         break;
     }
   };
   ```